# Ninja Intel Fortran dyndep ninja: build stopped: multiple rules generate Binaries

Tags: fortran, intel, ninja

Hi if ninja stopped like this where i can check first:

[5145/6609] Generating Fortran dyndep file CMakeFiles\mystran.dir\Fortran.dd
ninja: build stopped: multiple rules generate Binaries/mod/allocated_memory_use_ifs.mod.

the Fortran.dd

```
..
build CMakeFiles\\mystran.dir\\Source\\USE_IFs\\ALLOCATED_MEMORY_USE_IFs.f90.obj | Binaries\mod\allocated_memory_use_ifs.mod: dyndep | Binaries\mod\outa_here_interface.mod Binaries\mod\write_alloc_mem_table_interface.mod
  restat = 1

build CMakeFiles\\mystran.dir\\Source\\UTIL\\ALLOCATED_MEMORY.f90.obj: dyndep | Binaries\mod\allocated_array_data.mod Binaries\mod\allocated_memory_use_ifs.mod Binaries\mod\constants_1.mod Binaries\mod\debug_parameters.mod Binaries\mod\iount1.mod Binaries\mod\params.mod Binaries\mod\pentium_ii_kind.mod Binaries\mod\scontr.mod
```